# How to use DisplayNameFor with a class constant?

Tags: asp.net-core, html-helper

I have this class and would like to display user friendly names. How to do it?

```
public static class NavigationRoles
{ 
    [Display(Name = "Structure d'offre de service")]
    public const string STRUCTURES = "STRUCTURES";
}
```

Trying this `@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => NavigationRoles.STRUCTURES)` in my view returns an `InvalidOperationException`: ***Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions***.

Comment: My localization deep dive might help you: https://joonasw.net/view/aspnet-core-localization-deep-dive :)

Comment: I guess you need a property not an attribute. Try adding `{get;set;}`

Comment: Thank you @AntonToshik you are right. Thanks!

Comment: You don't need the set, especially if this is supposed to be a constant. Just do: `public string STRUCTURES { get; } = "STRUCTURES";`.